# Extract only patterns using regex, bash, multiline

Tags: regex, bash, pattern-matching, extract, multiline

I have some logs (witch are very huge, some can have 1GB+) and I would like to make a script which is able to extract all logs to a given regex.

Logs example:

```
27 Oct 2016 18:04:05,215 DEBUG org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowPageFilter[[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - Filtering request for path /framework/skeletons/application/setVariables.jsp
27 Oct 2016 18:04:05,215 DEBUG org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.DefaultPageFlowEventReporter[[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - beginPageRequest: Request=com.bea.p13n.servlets.PortalServletFilter$ParamFilteredRequest@18449c85, Response=org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag
.common.core.ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper@18378bd8
<Oct 27, 2016 6:04:05 PM EEST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "185" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 185181 ms
[
GET /application/appmanager/portal/myportal HTTP/1.1
.......
]
>
27 Oct 2016 18:04:05,215 DEBUG org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowPageFilter[[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - Filtering request for path /framework/skeletons/application/setVariables.jsp
27 Oct 2016 18:04:05,215 DEBUG org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.DefaultPageFlowEventReporter[[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - beginPageRequest: Request=com.bea.p13n.servlets.PortalServletFilter$ParamFilteredRequest@18449c85, Response=org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag
.common.core.ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper@18378bd8
<Oct 27, 2016 6:04:05 PM EEST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "185" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 185181 ms
[
GET /application/appmanager/portal/myportal HTTP/1.1
.......
]
>
<Oct 27, 2016 6:04:05 PM EEST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "185" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 185181 ms
[
GET /application/appmanager/portal/myportal HTTP/1.1
.......
]
>
27 Oct 2016 18:04:05,215 DEBUG org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowPageFilter[[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - Filtering request for path /framework/skeletons/application/setVariables.jsp
27 Oct 2016 18:04:05,215 DEBUG org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.DefaultPageFlowEventReporter[[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - beginPageRequest: Request=com.bea.p13n.servlets.PortalServletFilter$ParamFilteredRequest@18449c85, Response=org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag
.common.core.ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper@18378bd8
<Oct 27, 2016 6:04:05 PM EEST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '120' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "185" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 185181 ms
[
GET /application/appmanager/portal/myportal HTTP/1.1
.......
]
```

I would like to make this pattern configurable, to be able to search some type of errors for example.

Now I know this regex is matching any log I need (it has a problem with last matching in file):

```
.+?(?=(^\d{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{4}.)|(^<[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{2},\s\d{4}\s))
```

But I am not sure how to say it to match only error logs for example. The above regex return me an entire log (which is good), but I want to be matched only if it contains some char sequences like "ERROR"

Thanks

Comment: Why not pipe it through a *second* pattern match, looking for 'ERROR' ?

Comment: Not sure how to extract it or what command should I use. I would like this matching to send it to a file

Comment: Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: unclear how you can know how to use a complex regex, but don't know how to filter on a plain string. Does `grep 'fancyregex' file | grep -i error` give you any ideas? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You want to match lines starting with a date which also contains the keyword `Error`?

```
grep -E '(^[[:digit:]]{2} [[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{4}|^<[[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{2}, [[:digit:]]{4}).*Error' file.log
```

Might want to jam in a `-i` to be in case sensitive:

```
grep -iE '...' file.log
```